# Calling a method that displays array content

Tags: c#, arrays

I am confused as to what to put as the parameter for "output();"

I need to have it display the content of the array that has been created but I am getting confused as its an array and not just a variable... I thought it should be output(value); but that and many other guesses you might say have not worked.

I was taught you put in there what variables you created in main but that did not work.

```
using System;


namespace Lab16
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int value;

        Console.Write("How big of an Array? ");
        int arraySize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr = new int[arraySize];

        for (int i = 0; i <= arraySize - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("First Value: ");
            value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }

        output();
    }

    static void output(ref int value, ref Array arr, ref int arraySize)
    {

        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            for (int v = 1; v <= arraySize; v++)
            {
                string number = "Number: ";

                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1} {2}", number, v, i);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are calling ouput but not passing anything when it is expecting 3 parameters ?

Comment: Why do you pass the `value` argument? Just pass the array and loop thru it to print its content!

Comment: Also now that someone explained it. I have gone back and it the checkbox for the best answer on ALL previous questions.

Comment: @thatdude - apologies for not explaining - respect for taking action

Comment: @thatdude good ! That will certainly help when you want people to answer your questions. The best answer is actually a really important part of the Question/Answer model of StackExchange sites.

Comment: I totally agree, I thought originally it was just "helpful button" below answer. Thanks for the education everyone and thank you for the push in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, why all the refs? They seem to not serve any purpose, as well as the first parameter which is never used:

```
static void output(Array arr, int arraySize)
    {

        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            for (int v = 1; v <= arraySize; v++)
            {
                string number = "Number: ";

                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1} {2}", number, v, i);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now use

```
output(arr, arraySize);
```

The second parameter can also be stripped, since C# arrays hold their length in a field:

```
static void output(Array arr)
    {

        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            for (int v = 1; v <= arr.Length; v++)
            {
                string number = "Number: ";

                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1} {2}", number, v, i);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

and use:

```
 output(arr);
```

Comment: is the `arraySize` parameter needed either? - oh and +1

Comment: @Andras Zoltan: Not really. I'll make a note of that.

Comment: I now understand the ACCEPT answer function. Sorry bout not using it prior to today. Thank you for this, I forgot about order. THat being arr, arraySize order when I passed these to the method.

Answer (score 2):

You should send the array as a parameter to this method:

```
static void output(int[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i< arr.Length; i++)
    {

        string number = "Number: ";
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1} ", number, arr[i]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
 static void output(int[] myArray)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i< myArray.Length; i++)
   {

    string number = "Number: ";
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1} {2}", number, v, i);
    Console.ReadLine();
   }
 }
```

but dont forget to pass the parameters when you call the function :

`output(myArray)`

because output is expecting to receive an array. Drop all the ref too.

The  `myArray.Length` already stores the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the value parameter is for, but arr would be your array, arr, and arraySize is your variable arraySize. So do output(value, arr, arraySize)